# Uncaught ReferenceError: autocomplete is not defined

Tags: javascript

We currently have some Javascript that used to work, however we recently underwent a system upgrade, and we are doing some regression testing.

Now our script is not recognizing our function anymore:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: autocomplete is not defined

However, it seems like the issue is related to how the function is defined, and my JS is unfortunately very basic.

Our declaration is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function (global, factory) {
  typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? module.exports = factory() :
  typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(factory) :
  (global = global || self, global.autocomplete = factory());
}
(this, function () { 'use strict';
/*
     * https://github.com/kraaden/autocomplete
     * Copyright (c) 2016 Denys Krasnoshchok
     * MIT License
     */         
function autocomplete(settings) {
```

Any assistance or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Edit: Just an additional error received when other JS on the page executes:

> Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function () { 'use strict';

Comment: Have you returned the function?

Comment: Hi, yes, at the very end:

`return autocomplete;
});`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the new upgrade uses a different requirejs library.

We reverted to the old library, and our code is now working.

(we will investigate and resolve the code dependency at a later point, so that the new library can be used.)